In a monoidal category with duals is the coevaluation map determined by the evaluation?
For a monoidal category $(\mathcal{M},\otimes,1)$ and an object $X$ with a left dual $X^*$. Let $(e,c)$ be a pair of (co)evaluation maps for the pair $(X,X^*)$. Is it possible to have another map $c': 1 \to V \otimes V^*$ such that $(e,c')$ is also a (co)evaluation pair of maps. I guess the answer is no, and that this is also true for a pair $(e',c)$. This would mean that $c$ can be uniquely expressed in terms of $e$, if this is the case, what is this expression?
As a quick sanity check, we see that this is the case for the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces, where the non-degenerate bilinear form determines a dual basis.

If $(e,c)$ and $(e,c')$ both satisfy the snake equations, then $c=c'$:

However, for an arbitrary morphism $E:V^*\otimes V\to 1$ there is no reason to expect that there should exist a $C:1\to V\otimes V^*$ such that $(E,C)$ satisfy the snake equations.
So you can't expect a formula expressing $c$ in terms of $e$, because if there were one you could apply it to any $E$ above.

Araújio: The identity in the middle comes from associativity?

@Yilmaz It follows from "level exchange," where you can pull morphisms past each other by composing with the identity, similar to your other question.
